# Вопрос по DATA STUDIO

Tags: sql, google-analytics, firebaseanalytics

буду признателен, если найдется тот кто разбирается в datastudio.google.com.

У меня данные тянутся из firebase, и вопрос мой в том, как получить выборку конкретных событий из поля `eventName`.
Я делаю выборку из поля `eventName`, в котором есть событие `fa_click_777`.

Выводится все корректно, но после `else` выводится поле, в котором все оставшиеся события. Как мне выводить только поле `fa_click_777` и его значения и больше ничего?

```sql
CASE 
 WHEN Event Name IN ("fa_click_777") THEN "777"
ELSE "" 
 END
```